# Android UI Designing tool

Tags: android

Are there any programs that I can use to design my UI for Android? I need to make a design for presentation, I need something like Paint with drag & drop Android views and widgets.

P.S. Don't offer Eclipse layout design view, it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Nothing that's any good.  Unless someone knows otherwise...

Comment: Yeah, I found few, but they are terrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cacoo has some support for doing mock ups for Android as well as iOS. The image I made below in like 30s. It has a free mode but with some limitations with saving and exporting you can always just take screen shots and save those.

[image: Design mock up]

https://cacoo.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one:
http://www.droiddraw.org/

Just double click to add widgets, and drag and drop to replace.

Please note that it uses `AbsoluteLayout` by default which is deprecated.

Comment: I will try, thanks.
And you can change layout type.